# Does cuda-gdb automatically pick the correct focus for a CUDA_EXCEPTION_5 Warp out-of-range address error?

Tags: debugging, exception, cuda

I have a kernel that's failing with CUDA_EXCEPTION_5, Warp Out-of-range Address.

cuda-gdb automatically places the focus on a specific block.  Is that the block where the error is occuring or when nvidia documentation states CUDA_EXCEPTION_5 "is not precise" it means the debugger can't determine which block/thread that specific exception occurred in?

If it's only granular to the warp is there a way to find out within cuda-gdb which warp the exception occurred within and which blocks belong to that warp?

Comment: Have you tried using cuda-memcheck? Make sure to compile with the -g option (if using Linux).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cuda-gdb is not always able to precisely detect thread where the exception was thrown. To increase the precision you need to enable memcheck integration before starting your application by using "set cuda memcheck on" command. Please note that running the application with integrated memcheck enabled degrades the performance.

Comment: Off-topic, I read that cuda-memcheck can't find local read errors when run within cuda-gdb.  Did I understand that correctly?  Also if I don't configure any autostep settings does it step through all the code line by line or will cuda-memcheck possibly miss errors?

Answer (score 2):

In CUDA 5.0, cuda-memcheck when used from within cuda-gdb has similar memory access error detection capabilities as when run standalone. The standalone cuda-memcheck application has additional capabilities such as detection of race conditions, detection of memory leaks as well as the ability to continue past the first error. Cuda-memcheck is not related to autostep, and when integrated with cuda-gdb will precisely stop the application at the first detected error from an out of bound or misaligned memory accesses.